# WHERE clause for each SELECT field?

Tags: mysql

```
id  by  for  amount
 1   8   5     50
 2   5   7     30
 3   6   5     80
 4   5   3     40
```

How can i do something like

```
 SELECT SUM(`amount`)[//WHERE for=5] - SUM(`amount`)[//WHERE by=5] FROM table
 i.e. 130-70
```

so i have a table..
and i want to perform a query like the above one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement

```
SELECT SUM(case when `for`=5 then `amount` else 0 end) - 
       SUM(case when `by`=5 then `amount` else 0 end)
FROM table
```

that adds `amount` only for a specific case and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Short explanation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT((SELECT SUM(amt) FROM tablename WHERE for = 5) - 
      (SELECT SUM(amt) FROM tablename WHERE by = 5)) 
FROM tablename;
```

Worked for me in MySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html/)  function:

```
SELECT SUM( IF(`for`=5, `amount`, 0)) - 
       SUM( IF(`by`=5,  `amount`, 0))
FROM tablename
```

`IF()` works as follows:

```
IF(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)
```

I use  `IF()` within `SUM()` **to add** `amount`, **if** `for/by` is equals to `5` **else** `0` will be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
  SUM(
 CASE
    WHEN _for = 5
    THEN amount
    ELSE 0
 END
 ) - SUM(
 CASE
    WHEN _by = 5
    THEN amount
    ELSE 0
 END
 ) AS val
  FROM temp
```